# rsyslog 5.8 imfile outside /var/log not picking up log files

Tags: redhat, rsyslog

I would like to pick up logs of different types from various locations other than /var/log and send them to a central location.

Using RH 6.6 and rsyslog 5.8 the configuration works fine when using path within /var/log. If I use other path like /opt/appname/log/file.log. The rsyslog client does not pick up the log. I do not see any error or message when running rsyslogd in debug mode.

Example:
Client:

```
   ...
   $InputFileName /opt/appname/test.log
   $InputFileTag APPNAME1
   $InputFileStateFile stat-APPNAME1
   $InputFileSeverity info
   $InputFilePersistStateInterval 200
   $InputFileFacility local3 # alto tried with other local
   $InputRunFileMonitor
   ...
```

Server:

```
   ...
   $template HostAudit, "/opt/logs/%HOSTNAME%/test.log"  # tried differnt path
   $template auditFormat, "%msg%\n"
   local3.*                                ?HostAudit;auditFormat
   ...
```

Any recommendations?, I appreciate your help!!!

Bill

Comment: If you've run `rsyslog` in debug mode, is it safe to assume you've also run `rsyslog -N 1` to verify the syntax of your config files?

Answer (score 0):

I would first try these:

- Verify that the state file names are unique
- Verify that every $InputFileName points to an existing regular file
- Remove some of the files that you want to be monitored from the configuration. It could be that there is a problem with only one of the monitored files.  That would make rsyslog ignore the rest of the files.

I had this with `"$InputFileStateFile tomcat-log"` for each of the individual tomcat logs.  Each of the state file name needs to be unique.  For me it worked by changing it to instances of:

```
"$InputFileStateFile tomcat-manager"
"$InputFileStateFile tomcat-localhost"
```

etc... 
Another option is to just add numbers to the end of the state file name.

```
"$InputFileStateFile tomcat-log1"
"$InputFileStateFile tomcat-log2"
```